# Como substituir​ um caractere do meio de uma string e trocar por dois caracteres?

Tags: c, string

Por exemplo,

```
Char s1 [  ] = "azul";
 Char S2 [ ] = "z";
Char S3 [ ] = "PP";

Puts(s1); //azul
```

Código para substituir...

Resultado esperado:

```
Puts(s1); //aPPul
```

Obs.: Consegui fazer alterando 1 caractere por outro, mas 1 por 2 e ainda manter os caracteres subsequentes, não.

Comment: o que é o tipo `Chris`?

Comment: É tipo char, consertei na edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem escapatória: você vai ter que alocar outro lugar para armazenar o seu resultado.  Fazendo isso você pode depois substituir a sua sequência de caracteres e ter espaço suficiente para guardar tudo:

```
char *
substituir(char * original, char busca, char * subst) {
    int i, num_inst;
    char * ptr, * ptr2, * resultado;

    /* conta o número de instâncias de busca em original */
    for (ptr = original, num_inst = 0; *ptr; ptr ++) {
        if (*ptr == busca) num_inst ++;
    }
    /* aloca memória suficiente para guardar o resultado */
    resultado = malloc(
        strlen(original)/* letras no original */
        + (strlen(subst) - 1) * num_inst /* número de caracteres extra para caberem as instâncias de subst */
        + 1 /* para o '\0' final */
    );
    if (resultado == NULL) return resultado; /* se não conseguiu alocar memória, retorne */
    for (ptr = original, ptr2 = resultado;
         * ptr; ) {
        if (*ptr == busca) {
            /* concatene a sequência de substituição e depois ache o fim da string */
            strcat(ptr2, subst);
            while (* ptr2) ptr2 ++;
            ptr ++; // tem que avançar o ponteiro de original, também
        } else {
            /* copie o byte */
            *ptr2 ++ = *ptr ++;
        }
    }
    * ptr2 = '\0';

    return resultado;
}
```

Note que o código acima aloca uma *string* nova, então se você for substituir a antiga e esta for alocada dinamicamente, lembre-se de chamar `free()` nela! Note também que `original` não foi tocada e permanece com o valor original.

Comment: Wtmute, obrigado pela dica. Mas, tenho uma dúvida: qual a lógica no primeiro "for" para que a condição de parada seja "*ptr"?

Comment: `*ptr`, como você sabe, desreferencia o ponteiro, isto é, traz o valor guardado no endereço de memória apontado por `ptr`. Quando um valor vem sem um operador lógico como `==` ou `<`, é equivalente a testar se ele é diferente de zero. Como as _strings_ em C terminam sempre com o caracter zero (`'\0'`), isto é equivalente a parar quando chega ao final da _string_. É uma construção muito idiomática em C.

Comment: Entendi e gostei muito da dica. A partir de agora vou tentar encontrar outras situação para utilizar.